# AWS Upload to S3 through Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Trying to upload pictures to S3 from lambda. I get a return code of 200 when uploading the picture from my phone but the image is never uploaded to the bucket? Is it something to do with a bucket policy? The lambda function :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    
    region: 'us-west-2'
})
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});
   // var buf = Buffer.from(event.picture.imageBinary.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""),'base64')
     let encodedImage =JSON.parse(event.picture);
     let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, 'base64');
     var filePath = "avatars/" + event.userid + ".jpg"
     var params = {
        Body: decodedImage,
        Bucket: 'testpictures-1',
        Key: filePath,
        ContentEncoding: 'base64',
        ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
    };
    
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err){ console.log(err, err.stack);} // an error occurred
   else     {console.log(data);}           // successful response
   
   
   

  
 });
    
};
```

Comment: A failed upload would not result in a 200 OK response. No bucket policy will cause this to happen. If you see 200, your object was uploaded. How are you determining that the image was not uploaded to the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to invoke the Amazon S3 Service from a Lambda function, you must ensure that the IAM role associated with the Lambda function has the correct S3 policies. If the IAM role does not have the policies related to an AWS Service , then you cannot successfully invoke the AWS Service from a Lambda function. Here is an AWS tutorial (implemented in Java) that discusses this point.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events